# How to display subcategories under category in grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to display subcategories under related categories. For example:

```
 Category
 SubCategory
 SubCategory
 SubCategory

 Category
 SubCategory
 SubCategory
 SubCategory

Category
 SubCategory
 SubCategory
 SubCategory
```

Followings are domain classed related to category and SubCategory:

**Category.groovy**

```
class Category {

    String name
    String description
    static constraints = {
    }
    static hasMany = [ subCategories: SubCategory ]
```

}

**SubCategory.groovy**

```
class SubCategory {

        String name

        static hasMany = [requirements: Enquiry]
        static belongsTo = [ category: Category]
        static constraints = {
            requirements nullable:true
        }
    }
```

**ShowCreateEnquiry** Where I tried to write logic for getting category and related subcategories.

```
def showCreateEnquiry() {
        def reqCode = Util.generateUniqueReqCode()
        EnquiryCommand enquiryInstance = new EnquiryCommand();
        enquiryInstance.setReqCode(reqCode) ;
        def marketlist = Category.list(params.id)
        def subCategoryList = marketlist?.subCategories
        render ( view: "showCreateEnquiry" , model:[ "enquiryInstance": enquiryInstance, "marketlist": marketlist] )
    }
```

Now I want something like this: Someone told me that I can create groovy list in above action, where I can pass parameter of category and subcategories and use those variable in GSP and use 2 for or each loop to iterate category and subcategory. 
Could anyone help me achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is the solution according to what I understand :)

**showCreateEnquiry.gsp**

```
<g:each in="${marketlist}" var="category">
    <p>${category.name}</p>
    <g:each in="${category.subCategories}" var="subCategory">
      <p>${subCategory.name}</p>
    </g:each>
</g:each>
```

In addition you don't need to include `enquiryInstance` in model for rendering. And use css for styling your view.

Comment: hi @emilan, this worked like charm :). Can I use groovy list to find category and its related subcategories in above action and pass category and subcategories as paramters. What do you say on this ?

Comment: Something like this.  def findAllSubCategories(category, results = []) {
   category.subCategories.each { child ->
      results << child
      findAllChildren(child, results)
   }
}

Comment: Sure, you can. There could be so many workaround solutions for this kind of issue, but I recommend you to use above mentioned solution, I think it's brief and good enough.

Comment: hi @emilan, the approach we are following, is fine in case editing this page i.e editing Enquiry page?